# Joining ID's for a combobox

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, combobox

I have two tables with "Field Name" columns.  Some Table B field names are the same as Table A field names.  If that is the case, I want to exclude those from the combobox so I don't have a double (I only want the Table A field name in that case).  I also need the ID's (unique to each table) in the combobox.

I can't seem to come up with the right SQL logic.  Right now, I'm trying the following

```
SELECT [fldID], [fldName] FROM OISInfo UNION 
(SELECT [ID], [Field Name] FROM FldDef 
LEFT JOIN OISInfo ON [Field Name] = [fldName] WHERE [fldName] IS NULL)
```

but Access keeps telling me that the join expression is not supported (in the bracketed part).  The table names are definitely correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested.Worked perfectly. Table5 is your table A or maybe OISInfo. Table 6 is your table B (FldDef)

```
 SELECT Table5.ID, Table5.Field1
 FROM Table5
 UNION
 SELECT Table6.ID, Table6.Field1
 FROM Table6 LEFT JOIN Table5 ON Table6.[Field1] = Table5.[Field1]
 WHERE (((Table5.Field1) Is Null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Union takes cares of doubles, this is all you have to do

```
SELECT [fldID], [fldName] FROM OISInfo
UNION
SELECT [ID], [Field Name] FROM FldDef
```

Comment: The ID's do not match up though, only the field names are doubles.  As a result, all the doubles still appear in the list.

Comment: Then you will have to remove the ID fields from the query then, if you're trying to do a union where `fldName` and `Field Name` doubles are removed and still have IDs then it isn't possible.  You will have to either not have either ID or choose 1 table that you follow the IDs of

Comment: That seems hard to believe.  A clever join should be able to do the trick. I guess I'll just keep working at it!

Comment: I must be misunderstanding you then if you think its possible.  Perhaps add an example case of what you mean in your question.